# Why does in-memory db context in EntityFramework depend on SQL Server Express?

Tags: entity-framework, configuration, sql-server-express, visual-studio-2017, in-memory

I test a project on two different machines with different results: on one machine it requires an instance of SQL Server Express to be running, while it runs fine on another without neither SQL Express or SQL Server to be running. Here are some details:

- The project uses Entity Framework (NuGet package 6.1.3)
- The db context is built in memory, by overriding a method Seed and providing some data
- Default connection factory is set to LocalDbConnectionFactory, that should prevent EF from using SQL Express as default

Here is the Entity Framework configuration section:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

So far so good. Now if I run the projects on a rusty Windows 8.1 machine with lots of old stuff installed (Visual Studio 2013, both SQL Server and SQL Express, older versions of .NET framework etc.) then everything works fine. However, attempt to run the same project on a fresh Windows 10 machine with just Visual Studio 2017 results with a failure after a long timeout and exception saying about not getting a response from SQL Server. Installing SQL Express, enabling TCP/IP and port 1483 and starting it fixed the problem.

This is not the first time I encounter that SQL Server dependency is sticky in a way for Entity Framework but now I am able to demonstrate it on two identical project instances running in different environment where one of them works as it should while the other one (fresh, latest and greatest) drags the unwanted dependency.

Comment: Do you have at least SQL Server LocabDB version 11 installed? It's a very, very minimal version of SQL Express, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb

Comment: No I didn't install this one on a fresh machine. Perhaps this could to the trick. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes, it worked on another machine with fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jessehouwing who suggested installing SQL Server LocabDB version 11, it now works on a fresh machine without SQL Server or SQL Server Express running as a service.